# How to extract units from text

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, select

I have product names. They contain units of: length(M), mass(KG, G), quantity(KS) and volume(L).

sample data:

[image]

```
Towels bam.m.3vrs.100%C.80ks
Towels Pet Expert 2x19m,2vrs.
Desserts 165g TK
Desserts AM 100g
```

The units are followed after number. How can i extract them ?

Comment: Not really "after number". `3vrs` - is "vrs" also *unit*? Or "x" in `2x`? Try to be more precise.

Comment: @Littlefoot They're after number.. only these units exists in system, which are listed here (M,KG,G,KS,L).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `regexp_replace()`, as:

```
regexp_replace(mycol, '.*\d(m|kg|g|ks|l).*', '\1')
```

The regexp searches for one of the pre-defined unit strings, preceded by a digit.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28e86f49e8b20b11ad5ff680f9c3af0d)**:

```
with t as (
    select 'Towels bam.m.3vrs.100%C.80ks' mycol from dual
    union all select 'Towels Pet Expert 2x19m,2vrs' from dual
    union all select 'Desserts 165g TK' from dual
    union all select 'Desserts AM 100g' from dual
)
select mycol, regexp_replace(mycol, '.*\d(m|kg|g|ks|l).*', '\1') myunit from t
```

```
MYCOL                        | MYUNIT
:--------------------------- | :-----
Towels bam.m.3vrs.100%C.80ks | ks    
Towels Pet Expert 2x19m,2vrs | m     
Desserts 165g TK             | g     
Desserts AM 100g             | g
```

Comment: @Georgy: `regexp_replace(mycol, '.*\d(m|kg|g|ks|l).*', '\1', 1, 1, 'i')`